# GNOME DevHelp for Microsoft Window

Tags: gnome, gtk, helpfile

Can anyone please tell

1. If DevHelp application is available for Microsoft Window or not?
2. I have installed libgtk-3-doc on Ubuntu. Where the doc files are saved on the machine,so that I can use it to convert in chm or some other format, in order to use it on windows.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the HTML-files under `/usr/share/doc/libgtk-3-doc/gtk3`. A full list of all files coming with the package libgtk-3-doc you can obtain by executing this command:

```
dpkg -L libgtk-3-doc
```

on a virtual terminal or a terminal window.

Comment: May also be installed in `$HOME/.local/share/doc/`